# Using SymPy nsolve to return real solutions of system of 9 nonlinear equations

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to implement an algorithm from a paper. One of the steps is to solve a (seemingly overdetermined) system of 9 linear equations. Essentially, I am solving for 6 angles (3 corresponding to one 3D rotation operator and the other 3 corresponding to another 3D rotation operator). When I use SymPy's `nsolve` function, I get complex-valued solutions when the aforementioned angles must be real-valued.

At first, I tried using the following code to solve:

```
guess = [0]*6
for i in range(6):
    guess[i] = np.random.uniform(-math.pi/4, math.pi/4)
    
sol = sympy.nsolve(totMatEntries, variables, guess, verify=False)
```

where "totMatEntries" is a list of all 9 equations:

```
    [-(-(-0.211888898005819 + 0.000201858546688659*I)*(-sin(phi)*sin(theta)*sin(varphi) + cos(theta)*cos(varphi)) - (-0.100104758120491 - 0.00085365922969724*I)*(sin(phi)*sin(varphi)*cos(theta) + sin(theta)*cos(varphi)) + (-0.0493972282408545 + 0.000555985273887699*I)*sin(varphi)*cos(phi) + 0.042245086780191 - 0.0077632870942472*I)*sin(gamma)*cos(beta) + (-(-0.211888898005819 + 0.000201858546688659*I)*(sin(phi)*sin(theta)*cos(varphi) + sin(varphi)*cos(theta)) - (-0.100104758120491 - 0.00085365922969724*I)*(-sin(phi)*cos(theta)*cos(varphi) + sin(theta)*sin(varphi)) - (-0.0493972282408545 + 0.000555985273887699*I)*cos(phi)*cos(varphi) - 0.00967789639697698 - 0.00253968886387741*I)*sin(beta) + (-(-0.0493972282408545 + 0.000555985273887699*I)*sin(phi) + (-0.211888898005819 + 0.000201858546688659*I)*sin(theta)*cos(phi) - (-0.100104758120491 - 0.00085365922969724*I)*cos(phi)*cos(theta) + 0.0456619648508618 - 0.00966526311536431*I)*cos(beta)*cos(gamma),
     (-(-0.000236984557634061 - 0.00097001184498303*I)*sin(phi) + (0.00783165321208983 + 0.000853659229697511*I)*sin(theta)*cos(phi) - (-0.00111992617041071 - 0.00155902634024032*I)*cos(phi)*cos(theta) + 0.12992906519316 - 0.0390982542800826*I)*cos(beta)*cos(gamma) - (-(0.00783165321208983 + 0.000853659229697511*I)*(-sin(phi)*sin(theta)*sin(varphi) + cos(theta)*cos(varphi)) - (-0.00111992617041071 - 0.00155902634024032*I)*(sin(phi)*sin(varphi)*cos(theta) + sin(theta)*cos(varphi)) + (-0.000236984557634061 - 0.00097001184498303*I)*sin(varphi)*cos(phi) - 0.0797670305369711 - 0.0332868851741353*I)*sin(gamma)*cos(beta) + (-(0.00783165321208983 + 0.000853659229697511*I)*(sin(phi)*sin(theta)*cos(varphi) + sin(varphi)*cos(theta)) - (-0.00111992617041071 - 0.00155902634024032*I)*(-sin(phi)*cos(theta)*cos(varphi) + sin(theta)*sin(varphi)) - (-0.000236984557634061 - 0.00097001184498303*I)*cos(phi)*cos(varphi) + 0.0344940742297929 - 0.00791576520793481*I)*sin(beta),
     (-(0.00697281792643772 - 0.00247902218183044*I)*sin(phi) + (0.0206806514003599 + 0.00370002375247188*I)*sin(theta)*cos(phi) - (0.0152940316314626 - 0.00782279178229296*I)*cos(phi)*cos(theta) - 0.058756745958481 - 0.0173983727642744*I)*cos(beta)*cos(gamma) - (-(0.0206806514003599 + 0.00370002375247188*I)*(-sin(phi)*sin(theta)*sin(varphi) + cos(theta)*cos(varphi)) - (0.0152940316314626 - 0.00782279178229296*I)*(sin(phi)*sin(varphi)*cos(theta) + sin(theta)*cos(varphi)) + (0.00697281792643772 - 0.00247902218183044*I)*sin(varphi)*cos(phi) + 0.101270227748623 - 0.0149299109130871*I)*sin(gamma)*cos(beta) + (-(0.0206806514003599 + 0.00370002375247188*I)*(sin(phi)*sin(theta)*cos(varphi) + sin(varphi)*cos(theta)) - (0.0152940316314626 - 0.00782279178229296*I)*(-sin(phi)*cos(theta)*cos(varphi) + sin(theta)*sin(varphi)) - (0.00697281792643772 - 0.00247902218183044*I)*cos(phi)*cos(varphi) - 0.06307348211128 - 0.00337522200088681*I)*sin(beta),
     (-sin(alpha)*sin(beta)*sin(gamma) + cos(alpha)*cos(gamma))*(-(-0.211888898005819 + 0.000201858546688659*I)*(-sin(phi)*sin(theta)*sin(varphi) + cos(theta)*cos(varphi)) - (-0.100104758120491 - 0.00085365922969724*I)*(sin(phi)*sin(varphi)*cos(theta) + sin(theta)*cos(varphi)) + (-0.0493972282408545 + 0.000555985273887699*I)*sin(varphi)*cos(phi) + 0.042245086780191 - 0.0077632870942472*I) + (sin(alpha)*sin(beta)*cos(gamma) + sin(gamma)*cos(alpha))*(-(-0.0493972282408545 + 0.000555985273887699*I)*sin(phi) + (-0.211888898005819 + 0.000201858546688659*I)*sin(theta)*cos(phi) - (-0.100104758120491 - 0.00085365922969724*I)*cos(phi)*cos(theta) + 0.0456619648508618 - 0.00966526311536431*I) - (-(-0.211888898005819 + 0.000201858546688659*I)*(sin(phi)*sin(theta)*cos(varphi) + sin(varphi)*cos(theta)) - (-0.100104758120491 - 0.00085365922969724*I)*(-sin(phi)*cos(theta)*cos(varphi) + sin(theta)*sin(varphi)) - (-0.0493972282408545 + 0.000555985273887699*I)*cos(phi)*cos(varphi) - 0.00967789639697698 - 0.00253968886387741*I)*sin(alpha)*cos(beta),
     (-sin(alpha)*sin(beta)*sin(gamma) + cos(alpha)*cos(gamma))*(-(0.00783165321208983 + 0.000853659229697511*I)*(-sin(phi)*sin(theta)*sin(varphi) + cos(theta)*cos(varphi)) - (-0.00111992617041071 - 0.00155902634024032*I)*(sin(phi)*sin(varphi)*cos(theta) + sin(theta)*cos(varphi)) + (-0.000236984557634061 - 0.00097001184498303*I)*sin(varphi)*cos(phi) - 0.0797670305369711 - 0.0332868851741353*I) + (sin(alpha)*sin(beta)*cos(gamma) + sin(gamma)*cos(alpha))*(-(-0.000236984557634061 - 0.00097001184498303*I)*sin(phi) + (0.00783165321208983 + 0.000853659229697511*I)*sin(theta)*cos(phi) - (-0.00111992617041071 - 0.00155902634024032*I)*cos(phi)*cos(theta) + 0.12992906519316 - 0.0390982542800826*I) - (-(0.00783165321208983 + 0.000853659229697511*I)*(sin(phi)*sin(theta)*cos(varphi) + sin(varphi)*cos(theta)) - (-0.00111992617041071 - 0.00155902634024032*I)*(-sin(phi)*cos(theta)*cos(varphi) + sin(theta)*sin(varphi)) - (-0.000236984557634061 - 0.00097001184498303*I)*cos(phi)*cos(varphi) + 0.0344940742297929 - 0.00791576520793481*I)*sin(alpha)*cos(beta),
     (-sin(alpha)*sin(beta)*sin(gamma) + cos(alpha)*cos(gamma))*(-(0.0206806514003599 + 0.00370002375247188*I)*(-sin(phi)*sin(theta)*sin(varphi) + cos(theta)*cos(varphi)) - (0.0152940316314626 - 0.00782279178229296*I)*(sin(phi)*sin(varphi)*cos(theta) + sin(theta)*cos(varphi)) + (0.00697281792643772 - 0.00247902218183044*I)*sin(varphi)*cos(phi) + 0.101270227748623 - 0.0149299109130871*I) + (sin(alpha)*sin(beta)*cos(gamma) + sin(gamma)*cos(alpha))*(-(0.00697281792643772 - 0.00247902218183044*I)*sin(phi) + (0.0206806514003599 + 0.00370002375247188*I)*sin(theta)*cos(phi) - (0.0152940316314626 - 0.00782279178229296*I)*cos(phi)*cos(theta) - 0.058756745958481 - 0.0173983727642744*I) - (-(0.0206806514003599 + 0.00370002375247188*I)*(sin(phi)*sin(theta)*cos(varphi) + sin(varphi)*cos(theta)) - (0.0152940316314626 - 0.00782279178229296*I)*(-sin(phi)*cos(theta)*cos(varphi) + sin(theta)*sin(varphi)) - (0.00697281792643772 - 0.00247902218183044*I)*cos(phi)*cos(varphi) - 0.06307348211128 - 0.00337522200088681*I)*sin(alpha)*cos(beta),
     (sin(alpha)*sin(gamma) - sin(beta)*cos(alpha)*cos(gamma))*(-(-0.0493972282408545 + 0.000555985273887699*I)*sin(phi) + (-0.211888898005819 + 0.000201858546688659*I)*sin(theta)*cos(phi) - (-0.100104758120491 - 0.00085365922969724*I)*cos(phi)*cos(theta) + 0.0456619648508618 - 0.00966526311536431*I) + (sin(alpha)*cos(gamma) + sin(beta)*sin(gamma)*cos(alpha))*(-(-0.211888898005819 + 0.000201858546688659*I)*(-sin(phi)*sin(theta)*sin(varphi) + cos(theta)*cos(varphi)) - (-0.100104758120491 - 0.00085365922969724*I)*(sin(phi)*sin(varphi)*cos(theta) + sin(theta)*cos(varphi)) + (-0.0493972282408545 + 0.000555985273887699*I)*sin(varphi)*cos(phi) + 0.042245086780191 - 0.0077632870942472*I) + (-(-0.211888898005819 + 0.000201858546688659*I)*(sin(phi)*sin(theta)*cos(varphi) + sin(varphi)*cos(theta)) - (-0.100104758120491 - 0.00085365922969724*I)*(-sin(phi)*cos(theta)*cos(varphi) + sin(theta)*sin(varphi)) - (-0.0493972282408545 + 0.000555985273887699*I)*cos(phi)*cos(varphi) - 0.00967789639697698 - 0.00253968886387741*I)*cos(alpha)*cos(beta),
     (sin(alpha)*sin(gamma) - sin(beta)*cos(alpha)*cos(gamma))*(-(-0.000236984557634061 - 0.00097001184498303*I)*sin(phi) + (0.00783165321208983 + 0.000853659229697511*I)*sin(theta)*cos(phi) - (-0.00111992617041071 - 0.00155902634024032*I)*cos(phi)*cos(theta) + 0.12992906519316 - 0.0390982542800826*I) + (sin(alpha)*cos(gamma) + sin(beta)*sin(gamma)*cos(alpha))*(-(0.00783165321208983 + 0.000853659229697511*I)*(-sin(phi)*sin(theta)*sin(varphi) + cos(theta)*cos(varphi)) - (-0.00111992617041071 - 0.00155902634024032*I)*(sin(phi)*sin(varphi)*cos(theta) + sin(theta)*cos(varphi)) + (-0.000236984557634061 - 0.00097001184498303*I)*sin(varphi)*cos(phi) - 0.0797670305369711 - 0.0332868851741353*I) + (-(0.00783165321208983 + 0.000853659229697511*I)*(sin(phi)*sin(theta)*cos(varphi) + sin(varphi)*cos(theta)) - (-0.00111992617041071 - 0.00155902634024032*I)*(-sin(phi)*cos(theta)*cos(varphi) + sin(theta)*sin(varphi)) - (-0.000236984557634061 - 0.00097001184498303*I)*cos(phi)*cos(varphi) + 0.0344940742297929 - 0.00791576520793481*I)*cos(alpha)*cos(beta),
     (sin(alpha)*sin(gamma) - sin(beta)*cos(alpha)*cos(gamma))*(-(0.00697281792643772 - 0.00247902218183044*I)*sin(phi) + (0.0206806514003599 + 0.00370002375247188*I)*sin(theta)*cos(phi) - (0.0152940316314626 - 0.00782279178229296*I)*cos(phi)*cos(theta) - 0.058756745958481 - 0.0173983727642744*I) + (sin(alpha)*cos(gamma) + sin(beta)*sin(gamma)*cos(alpha))*(-(0.0206806514003599 + 0.00370002375247188*I)*(-sin(phi)*sin(theta)*sin(varphi) + cos(theta)*cos(varphi)) - (0.0152940316314626 - 0.00782279178229296*I)*(sin(phi)*sin(varphi)*cos(theta) + sin(theta)*cos(varphi)) + (0.00697281792643772 - 0.00247902218183044*I)*sin(varphi)*cos(phi) + 0.101270227748623 - 0.0149299109130871*I) + (-(0.0206806514003599 + 0.00370002375247188*I)*(sin(phi)*sin(theta)*cos(varphi) + sin(varphi)*cos(theta)) - (0.0152940316314626 - 0.00782279178229296*I)*(-sin(phi)*cos(theta)*cos(varphi) + sin(theta)*sin(varphi)) - (0.00697281792643772 - 0.00247902218183044*I)*cos(phi)*cos(varphi) - 0.06307348211128 - 0.00337522200088681*I)*cos(alpha)*cos(beta)]
```

This gave complex solutions, so I tried setting all six variables to be

```
real=True
```

but I still obtained complex-valued solutions. I tried looking online, but I didn't find any questions/answers specifically pertaining to SymPy's `nsolve` giving complex-valued solutions when real solutions are expected.

Comment: Can you share `totMatEntries`? Without it, there isn't much we can do to help you...

Comment: If the equations are linear and overdetermined then you should use something like `linsolve` or some other exact reduction. The `nsolve` function is for approximate numerical solution of systems that are neither under- nor over-determined. The fact that you get complex-valued solutions suggests that the equations are not linear though because nsolve would give real solutions for a real guess if the equations are linear (and real).

Comment: @Davide_sd Sorry just added. It might be a bit hard to read since the equations are long (all are implicitly = 0). From what I can tell they are all nonlinear equations of trigonometric functions.

Comment: @SillyGoose `nsolve` sees that your equations returns complex numbers (because it contains many complex numbers). Hence, it's going to use complex variable for the parameters (your angles). I'd say you have to try to formulate better what you're trying to solve. Do you want to solve for zero imaginary and real parts? Do you want to solve for zero absolute value? Note that these suggestions are based purely on looking at your equations. Maybe it's possible to reformulate the problem in a simpler way, but without knowing how these equations were computed, it's impossible to say.